# Break parallel.foreach?

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

**How do I break out of an [parallel.for](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for.aspx) loop?**

I have a pretty complex statement which looks like the following:

```
Parallel.ForEach<ColorIndexHolder>(ColorIndex.AsEnumerable(),
    new Action<ColorIndexHolder>((ColorIndexHolder Element) =>
    {
        if (Element.StartIndex <= I && Element.StartIndex + Element.Length >= I)
        {
            Found = true;
            break;
        }
    }));
```

Using parallel class, I can optimize this process by far. However; I cannot figure out how to break the parallel loop? The `break;` statement throws following syntax error:

> No enclosing loops out of which to break or continue

Comment: Would you expect that ALL parallel instances of the loop break at the same time?

Answer (score 212, accepted):

Use the [`ParallelLoopState.Break`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallelloopstate.break.aspx) method:

```
 Parallel.ForEach(list,
    (i, state) =>
    {
       state.Break();
    });
```

Or in your case:

```
Parallel.ForEach<ColorIndexHolder>(ColorIndex.AsEnumerable(),
    new Action<ColorIndexHolder, ParallelLoopState>((ColorIndexHolder Element, ParallelLoopState state) =>
    {
        if (Element.StartIndex <= I && Element.StartIndex + Element.Length >= I)
        {
            Found = true;
            state.Break();
        }
    }));
```

Comment: Thinking of a sequential foreach loop it's guaranteed that the items before the item that for whatever reason caused the break are processed. What about a Parallel.ForEach where order of the items does not necessarily have to be the order in which they are processed? Is it guaranteed as well that all items in an IEnumerable<...> before the one that invokes state.Break() are being processed and those coming after it are not? Although the former could be achieved somehow, I don't see how the latter would be possible at all.

Comment: @Hendrik Wiese: Docs say: `Calling the Break method informs the for operation that iterations after the current one don't have to execute. However, all iterations before the current one will still have to be executed if they haven't already.` and `there is no guarantee that iterations after the current one will definitely not execute.`

Comment: so then would `state.Stop()` be more appropriate to reliably achieve the expected results, as mentioned below by Mike Perrenoud and MBentley

Comment: Is there a more intuitive variable name than state?

Answer (score 54):

You do this by calling using the overload of `Parallel.For` or `Parallel.ForEach` which passes in a loop state, then calling [`ParallelLoopState.Break`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallelloopstate.break%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or [`ParallelLoopState.Stop`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallelloopstate.stop%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  The main difference is in how quickly things break - with `Break()`, the loop will process all items with an earlier "index" than the current.  With `Stop()`, it will exit as quickly as possible.

For details, see [How to: Stop or Break from a Parallel.For Loop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460721.aspx).

Comment: +1, it looks like a few of us here have the exact same answer :) -- oh and I got your back up there on that other comment man.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. Do you know when either break or stop are called, is it the case that the currently executing iterations are completed or does it stop the iterations mid way through execution?

Comment: @CeejeeB Currently executing operations complete.

Answer (score 19):

LoopState is certainly a great answer.  I found the previous answers had so much other stuff that it was hard to see the answer, so here is a simple case:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

Parallel.ForEach(SomeTable.Rows(), (row, loopState) =>
{
    if (row.Value == testValue)
    {
        loopState.Stop();  // Stop the ForEach!
    }       
    // else do some other stuff here.
});
```

Answer (score 12):

What you should be using is `Any`, rather than a foreach loop:

```
bool Found = ColorIndex.AsEnumerable().AsParallel()
    .Any(Element => Element.StartIndex <= I 
      && Element.StartIndex + Element.Length >= I);
```

`Any` is smart enough to stop as soon as it knows that the result must be true.

Comment: True. However, `Any` won't work if you have to perform some sort of other lookup or logic inside an iteration.

Comment: @dst3p Why do you think it wouldn't work?  Sure, if you're looking something up in some other data structure or doing other complex logic you need to be sure it's safe to do in a multithreaded context, but there are lots of ways to do both of those things that *are* safe.  Why would you think you couldn't look anything up or do any logic here?

Comment: you’re right, I’ve been living in a Java world for too long 

Answer (score 5):

Just use the `loopState` that can be provided.

```
Parallel.ForEach<ColorIndexHolder>(ColorIndex.AsEnumerable(),  
    new Action<ColorIndexHolder>((Element, loopState) => { 
        if (Element.StartIndex <= I && Element.StartIndex + Element.Length >= I) { 
            loopState.Stop();
        }     
}));
```

Look at this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460721.aspx) for an example.