# How to stop a Parallel.ForEach loop?

Tags: c#

I have this code to start a Parallel ForEach loop:

```
Parallel.ForEach<ListViewItem>(filesListView.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>(), new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount }, item => {
    if (CallToStop == true)
        {  
            //Code here to stop the loop!
        }        
    internalProcessStart(item);
});
```

I have some code which will check if there is a call to stop the threads, and then I would like to `break;` the code, but this doesn't work with Parallel.

I found the same [question by someone else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12571048/break-parallel-foreach), but their code is slighly different to mine, and I'm not sure where to put the `ParallelLoopState state`.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you edit in the ForEach loop body as well?

Comment: @KevinLe OK, Done!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rewrite as below:

```
Parallel.ForEach<ListViewItem>(
    filesListView.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>(), 
    new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount }, 
    (item, state) => 
    {
        if (CallToStop == true)
        {  
            state.Break();
        }        
        internalProcessStart(item);
    }
);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this is the code I used and it's working nicely. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think using this [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782721(v=vs.110).aspx) should work:

```
    Parallel.ForEach<ListViewItem>(filesListView.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>(), new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount }, (item , state)  => 
    {
        if (/*Stop condition here*/)
        { 
            state.Break(); 
        }        
        internalProcessStart(item);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [CancellationToken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken(v=vs.110).aspx) as in this [example (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256691(v=vs.110).aspx).

Try something like this:

CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

```
       // Use ParallelOptions instance to store the CancellationToken
        ParallelOptions po = new ParallelOptions();
        po.CancellationToken = cts.Token;
        po.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount;

        try
        {
            Parallel.ForEach<ListViewItem>(filesListView.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>(), po, item => {
                // po.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); //1
                if (CallToStop == true)
                {  
                    //Code here to stop the loop!
                    cts.Cancel();
                }
                if (po.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested == false)
                {        
                    internalProcessStart(item);
                }
            });
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException e)
        {
            // handle
        }
        finally
        {
            cts.Dispose();
        }
```

Or instead of setting `CallToStop = true` call `cts.Cancel()` directly.

Or you can uncomment //1 and let all threds that did not finished throw [OperationCanceledException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.operationcanceledexception(v=vs.110).aspx) (only use whenyou are stopping all parallel thread because of `CallToStop = true` is caused by error).

You can even pass the `cts.Token` into your `internalProcessStart(item,token)` and handle what to do if you cancel when internal process is already running.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. Conceptually, you need to pass the loopState to your lambda function.

```
Parallel.ForEach<int>(new List<int>(),
            new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount },
            (val, loopState) =>
            {
                if (val == 9) //enter your stopcondition here
                {
                    loopState.Stop();
                    return;
                }
            });
```