# break Parallel.ForEach if user press key 'c'

Tags: c#, console-application

If user press 'c' then Parallel.ForEach should break without cancelling started tasks. Now my program is waiting for user, how can I do that the user can write 'c' in any moment and program will cancel when started tasks have finished?

```
List<int> companies = new List<int> { 56, 1, 18, 26, 37, 45, 47, 50, 56, 60 };
Parallel.ForEach(companies, (company, state) =>
{
    if (Console.ReadKey().KeyChar == 'c')
    {
        state.Break();
    }

    MyFunction(company);
});
```

**EDIT - final solution:**

```
try
{
    List<int> companies = new List<int> { 78, 1, 18, 26, 37, 45, 47, 50, 56, 60 };
    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    ParallelOptions po = new ParallelOptions();
    po.CancellationToken = cts.Token;

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        if (Console.ReadKey().KeyChar == 'c')
        {
            cts.Cancel();
        }
    });

    Parallel.ForEach(companies, (company, state) =>
    {
        MyFunction(company);

        po.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    });
}
catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Cancelled program");
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop a Parallel.ForEach loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39777560/how-to-stop-a-parallel-foreach-loop)

Comment: Also while in the "MyFunction" section it wont terminate

Comment: You do realize that what you’re asking makes absolutely no sense at all?

Comment: Pass a `ParallelOptions` with a `CancellationToken`: `Parallel.ForEach(companies, options, (company, state) => { ... })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Console.ReadKey` method call should not be inside the `Parallel.ForEach`, instead, it should be directly after it.

Then, use that read key to cancel the foreach using a CancellationToken.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-cancel-a-parallel-for-or-foreach-loop

Comment: So I have to use cancellation token, not state.Break() ?

Comment: @AleksanderChelpski Read the article linked in the answer. It shows exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @AleksanderChelpski you need to use a cancellation token to inform the parallel loop that it needs to stop. At that point, the method that you use to stop execution is up to you.