# Break the Parallel ForEach from outside

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

Google didn't help me, SO neither.

```
var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(5000);
timer.Elapsed += BreakEvent;
timer.Enabled = true;

Parallel.ForEach<string>(fileNames, (fileName, state) =>
{
    try
    {
        ProcessFile(fileName);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
    finally
    {

    }
});
```

I would like to break this `ForEach` loop after 5 seconds (in `BreakEvent`).

Of course it could be a button or anything.

I know about breaking by (in my example)

```
state.Stop();
```

But it's still inside the loop.

Is it even possible?

**EDIT:**

For everyone who search to the other way, I just though about it:

```
var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(5000);

timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler((obj, args) =>
{
    state.Stop();
});

timer.Enabled = true;
```

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12571048/break-parallel-foreach)

Comment: @MassimilianoKraus that's what I thought initially, but that question relates to breaking from _inside_ the loop, rather than from outside.

Comment: Yes, it's all about breaking from inside.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest using *cancellation*:

```
// Cancel after 5 seconds (5000 ms)
using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(5000))
{
    var po = new ParallelOptions()
    {
        CancellationToken = cts.Token,
    };

    try
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(fileNames, po, (fileName) =>
        {
            //TODO: put relevant code here
        });
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException e)
    {
        //TODO: Cancelled 
    }
}
```

Comment: O, that's nice idea! :) I didn't think about it, thank You!